# How do I customize pagination view of ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on ag-grid and one thing I want is to change pagination view completely and make it appear something like below image. How can I achieve this?[image]

Comment: Not in a place where I can look at my code right now, but if I remember correctly, you have to replace the whole footer, as the foote contains the pagination control, and does not provide the means to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out one solution. We can create this pagination view separately and then trigger pagination on click like `api.paginationProxy.goToPage(47)`, this also works as expected when we are working on server side pagination.